# Reconstruct and transform JSON object from XQuery

Tags: json, marklogic, marklogic-8

Is it possible to reconstruct a JSON object in XQuery? Using XML, it's possible to use computed constructors to rebuild an element:

```
element { node-name($some-element) } {
  (: Do stuff with $some-element/(@*|node()) :)
}
```

But using JSON objects, it seems that it's not possible to reconstruct properties. I would like to do something like this, but this throws a syntax error:

```
object-node {
  for $p in $some-json-object/*
  return node-name($p) : $p
}
```

It looks like it's possible to workaround that by mutating the JSON object:

```
let $obj := json:object(document{xdmp:from-json($json)}/*)
let $_put :=  map:put($o, 'prop-name', $prop-val)
return xdmp:to-json($o)/node()
```

But this has some obvious limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be helpful for you:  http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/json

However, I often take a different approach in xQuery (being comfortable with XML). This may get some push-back from people here, but it is my approach:

Construct what you like in XML and then transform it.  If you make your XML in the http: //marklogic.com/xdmp/json/basic namespace, then you can just transform it to whatever complex JSON you desire using [json:transform-to-json](http://docs.marklogic.com/json:transform-to-json)  - since all of the hints to datatypes are in the attributes of the XML. The nice thing about this approach is that it is a nice middle format. I can transform to JSON  - or I can apply an XSLT transformation and get other XML if I desire.

It should be noted that json:transform-to-json has other modes of operation and can get datatype hints from your own schema as well. But I perfer the built-in schema.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid using json:object really is the way to use here. Could be worse though, you only need a few lines to copy all json properties. You also don't need that document{} constructor, nor the extra type cast to json:object. xdmp:from-json already returns a json:object:

```
let $org := xdmp:from-json($json)
let $new := json:object()
let $_ :=
  for $key in map:keys($org)
  return map:put($new, $key, map:get($org, $key))
return xdmp:to-json($new)/node()
```

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this blog post by @paxstonhare that uses a non-functional approach, rebuilding new JSON objects during the tree walk by mutating them using `map:put()`:

http://developer.marklogic.com/blog/walking-among-the-json-trees